# Changing focus to new form element programatically - complicated use case

Tags: angular, user-experience, angular-template

I'm building Angular4 application. I'm working with nice User Experience and navigation between form fields using only keyboard. I have such problem, when user are pressing `Tab` key and reach this `+` sign (pic 1), press `Enter` key on it then this button moves to the next line (pic 2), and the focus is lost. The question is how can I handle this `Enter` key to move focus to the next line and focus `selector` on it (with `Merchant URL` value by default).

Now when user presses `Enter` on `+` this button in template disappears because of *ngIf and new line is generated. Any advice how to make this to achieve nice keyboard user experience? How to change focus from disappearing `+` to next line component that is already not visible but at the end of handling `Enter` it will be visible.

Pic 1.
[image]

Pic 2.
[image]

[SOLUTION]

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
) { // bla bla bla }
```

Since I'm controlling my generated elements `id` in template I can store `id` of the element that I want to focus on during handling `Enter` key and I need to implement `AfterViewChecked`.

```
onEnter() {
    this.focusOn = 'my-generated-element-id';
    // put new model data to the array so template can generate new row
}

// this method is called very frequently so I only need to set focus
// when I need it and then clear focusOn variable.
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.focusOn) {
        let element = this._document.getElementById(this.focusOn);
        if (element) {
            element.focus();
            this.focusOn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is obviously a function to generate the new line right? Focus on the new line element when it is generated. If it is generated with a loop or ngIf, you just need to make sure you are calling a function to set focus to the proper element

Comment: Can you show the code that add the new line of form?

Comment: In general pressing `+` sign push new line `model data` to `array`. This `model data` has informations how to create new line. Then this `array` is iterated in template using `*ngFor` and new lines are generated from its elements (`model data`). I think I will need to prepare something really simple because pasting this what I have right now is too much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren) to track the `input` or whichever elements. Then subscribe to the changes in the `QueryList`. In there you can focus on the last instance added.

Here is a [minimal example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpq7hg)

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  name = 'Angular 6';
  items = ['Item1', 'item2'];
  @ViewChildren('input') inputs: QueryList<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputs.changes.subscribe(changes => {
      changes.last.nativeElement.focus();
    })
  }
  addItem() {
    this.items.push(`Item${this.items.length + 1}`)
  }
}
```

---

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input #input [placeholder]="item"/>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
```

---

This is if you want to focus on the input in the new line added. To keep focus on `+` button, you can use `ViewChild` instead. If thats not what you want, try creating a minimal example in Stackblitz.

Comment: Hi. I already solved it for my use case. Thank You very much. I think Your solution should also work.

Comment: I already added my solution to this problem in question. Do You see any problems with this solution. For my use case it works but I can be unaware of some problems.

Comment: Angular doesn't encourage DOM being manipulated outside of its renderer.  Also doesn't encourage injecting document object this way. You can probably do the same with a templateRef and ViewChild which will be more in an Angular way.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help. I will read more on `templateRef` and `ViewChild`. I just wanted to have possibility to focus element with specific generated string `id`.

Comment: Cool. I haven't understood the problem completely, but glad that things are working for you now. If you can update your question when you get free, with a minimal example in StackBlitz, I could take a look at it.

Comment: If I have more time I will prepare minimal example in StackBlitz :) Thank You!